# I cannot insert data to the correct user's database

Tags: java, android, oop

I have two activities called Register.java,Login.java and i have a fragment called AddFragment.java where users can share notes. In register i take user's informations and save them to the firebase real time database with a unique id then sends the id to addfragment for adding the note to user's database. But my problem is, it does not add to the correct users datafield, it adds to the current user. So, when i test the app and log in to the user before the last created user and add notes, it adds to the last user. I know i get the last users id but i cannot think anway to fix it.Below is my register activity and addFragment.

Register.java

```
    public void writeNewUser() {
        // Set reference for database
        firebaseDatabase = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance();
        databaseReference = firebaseDatabase.getReference("users");

        // Get the current user that uses the app
        currentUser = mauth.getCurrentUser();

        // Check if the current user is not null
        if (currentUser != null) {
            String getEmail = email.getText().toString();
            String getPassword = password.getText().toString();
            String getUsername = username.getText().toString();
            String userId = currentUser.getUid();
            User user = new User(getEmail, getPassword, getUsername);

            sendData(userId); // Pass the user ID to sendData() method

            // Use user ID as child instead of getEmail
            databaseReference.child(userId).setValue(user)
                    .addOnSuccessListener(new OnSuccessListener<Void>() {
                        @Override
                        public void onSuccess(Void aVoid) {
                            // User added successfully
                        }
                    })
                    .addOnFailureListener(new OnFailureListener() {
                        @Override
                        public void onFailure(@NonNull Exception e) {
                            // An error occurred while adding the user
                        }
                    });
        }
    }

    public void sendData(String userID) {
        SharedPreferences sharedPreferences = getSharedPreferences(SHARED_PREFS, Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
        SharedPreferences.Editor editor = sharedPreferences.edit();
        editor.putString("uid", userID);
        editor.apply();
    }
```

Addfragment.java(I did not want to copy paste all of the code. So i am sharing just the related parts.)

```
        //Get the userID sent from register.activity
        SharedPreferences sharedPreferences =getActivity().getSharedPreferences(SHARED_PREFS,Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
        String uid = sharedPreferences.getString("uid","");
        Toast.makeText(getActivity(), "uid is:"+uid, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

        //Initialize the firebase database
        firebaseDatabase = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance();
        databaseReference = firebaseDatabase.getReference("users").child(uid);

        private void insertUserinfo(){
        String course = courseName.getText().toString();
        String uni = uniName.getText().toString();
        String page = pages.getText().toString();
        String prices = price.getText().toString();

        SelInfos selInfos = new SelInfos(course,uni,page,prices);
        databaseReference.push().setValue(selInfos);
        Toast.makeText(getActivity(),"Data inserted successfully",Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    }
```

I want to get the correct user id, pass it to addFragment so insert data to the correct users database.

Answer (score 0):

To fix the issue and ensure that the notes are added to the correct user's database in the 'AddFragment', you should pass the user ID directly from the 'Register' activity to the 'AddFragment' instead of using 'SharedPreferences'. Here's how you can do it:

```
public class AddFragment extends Fragment {
// ... Your existing code ...

public static AddFragment newInstance(String userID) {
    AddFragment fragment = new AddFragment();
    Bundle args = new Bundle();
    args.putString("uid", userID);
    fragment.setArguments(args);
    return fragment;
}

// ... Your existing code ...
}
```

In the Register activity, after saving the user to the database, pass the user ID to the AddFragment using the newInstance method:
public class RegisterActivity extends AppCompatActivity {
// ... Your existing code ...

```
public void writeNewUser() {
    // ... Your existing code ...

    sendData(userId); 

    // ... Your existing code ...

    // After saving the user, navigate to AddFragment and pass the user ID as an argument
    AddFragment addFragment = AddFragment.newInstance(userId);
    getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction()
            .replace(R.id.fragment_container, addFragment)
            .commit();
}

// ... Your existing code ...
}
```